# Getting 64-bit Java browser plugin to work

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, browser, java, plugins

I've installed Java 64-bit on my Windows 7 machine, and have since installed many 64-bit versions of Java-based programs. Now however I have to start using a website using a Java applet, but the 64-bit version of Java doesn't have a browser plugin that works. After searching the web I found two possible solutions:

- Installing both Java 32-bit and 64-bit versions on the same machine. However after trying this I've found that the 32-bit version messes up the 64-bit version in some way (to the extent that the uninstallers didn't even work any more)
- Copying some files from java/bin into my Firefox plugins folder - but [all articles I found](http://www.techspot.com/blog/596/a-fix-for-java-applets-not-loading-in-firefox/) about this approach refer to files that don't exist in the latest 64-bit version.

Has anyone managed to get the Java browser plugin to run when 64-bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the article [Windows 7 - problem installing java](http://www.sevenforums.com/software/55055-problem-installing-java.html), the order of installation is important :

> If Java is installed and shows up in
>   Programs and features, then uninstall
>   it. [..]
>
> If you want both 32 and 64 bit java,
>   then download both the one under
>   (Windows) and the one under
>   (Windowsx64)
>
> if
>   you use both 32 and 64 bit browsers,
>   you can install both. Just install the
>   64 bit one first, then the 32 bit one,
>   or re install the 32 bit one over the
>   64 bit one if both are already
>   installed, because of a specific known
>   issue with both Javas installed.

If when installing both one messes up the other, you might have to do some acrobatics every time when upgrading Java. So **do not** set Java to auto-update.